# Is this Bayesian Network probability correct?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

I just extended a bayesian network that was on a ppt into [this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzd8I.png). I'm trying to get P(A,B,C,D,E) and I think it's P(A)P(B)P(C|A,B)P(D|C)P(E|C) but as I'm not sure, just wanted to check if it is correct.

[image: this form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! The general form is 
$p_{X_1,\ldots,X_n} = \prod_i p_{X_i\mid \pi(X_i)}$
where $\pi(X_i)$ are the parents of $X_i$.
Your form is correct.